# A valid xmpp chatbar?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, xmpp, chat

I'm search about a chatbar to integrate in my site.
I have an ejabber server and I want to insert a chat client on the bottom of every page of my site.
I don't need groups, roooms and so on, but simply a chat one2one and the list of friends to talk to.

Now I'm using iJab but doesn't work very well. Many times users see their friend's list empty even if they are online.

Some features in my site use PrototypeJs so chat sw that uses it is welcome

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Jappix Mini seems to be a solid option; however it uses jQuery instead of Prototype.  It is integrated within a larger social client, but can easily be configured to work as a standalone mini chat.  It handles my companies list of 1000+ concurrent users fairly well in my tests but I have not deployed it full scale yet.  You can test it out at http://mini.jappix.com.

Also, I would recommend checking it out from the SVN as I just committed roster sorting by contact name and a search function in the mini chat.  The project's source code can be found here: http://codingteam.net/project/jappix/doc/DevJappix